# If conditionals in ejs, best practices

Tags: html, ejs

I have a variable `enabled:"false"` in my json file, I am reading the data in my content variable in ejs file.

But when I check for the condition:

```
<% if(content.enabled) { %>
    <h1>foo</h1>
<% } %>
```

The condtion works for both `"true"` and `"false"`, It may not be the correct method for check.

What will be correct method for `if` conditionals including `==` too.

What are the best practices ?

Answer (score 1):

Your method correct only, u can add else condition also, like

```
<% if (content.enabled=="true" || content.enabled==true) { %>
   <h1>foo</h1>
<% } else { %>
  <h1>false content</h1>
<% } %>
```

Comment: It works for both true and false, so in this case it will go to if and print `foo`, I already mentioned that in my question.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you not to use `boolean` values as `string`. For example when you use `"false"` instead of `false`. JS recognise it as a truthy value. In JS all values are truthy except for `false`, `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, and `NaN`. So when you are saying `enabled:"false"`, it is true actually.

For a detailed info about truthy values check [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy).

For your question; in JSON set your variable like;

```
{ "enabled" : false }
```

and your code will work.

And for comparison, i suggest strict equality `===` because it is comparing values types too. For example;

```
0 == false //returns true
0 === false //returns false
```

you can find details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/tr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I'll try to update my json.